# borg backups end with connection timeout after upgrade

Tags: debian, borgbackup

I have upgraded my Debian server (from bullseye to bookworm), hosted at Hetzner. I use their Storage Box + borg as one of means of backup. However, since the upgrade, all my attempts to run `borg` end with `Connection timed out`. I am at a loss how to recover from this.

Version change of borg: 1.1.16-3 -> 1.2.4-1 (note: this is Debian versioning, but should correspond to actual borg versions

Script called (abridged):

```
BACKUP_DIR=/mnt/backup/mysql
export BORG_REPO=ssh://XYZ@XYZ.your-storagebox.de:23/./my-dir
export BORG_PASSPHRASE='mysecurepassphrase'

borg create                         \
--stats                         \
--list                          \
--show-rc                       \
--compression lz4               \
 ::'{hostname}-db-{now}'        \
 $BACKUP_DIR
```

output as provided when run with `--debug`

```
Sun Feb 25 07:53:31 PM CET 2024 Starting backup

using builtin fallback logging configuration
33 self tests completed in 0.05 seconds
SSH command line: ['ssh', '-p', '23', 'XYZ@XYZ.your-storagebox.de', 'borg-1.2', 'serve', '--debug']
Remote: ssh: connect to host XYZ.your-storagebox.de port 23: Connection timed out
Connection closed by remote host. Is borg working on the server?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/borg/archiver.py", line 5213, in main
    exit_code = archiver.run(args)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/borg/archiver.py", line 5144, in run
    return set_ec(func(args))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/borg/archiver.py", line 161, in wrapper
    repository = RemoteRepository(location.omit_archive(), create=create, exclusive=argument(args, exclusive),
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/borg/remote.py", line 578, in __init__
    raise ConnectionClosedWithHint('Is borg working on the server?') from None
borg.remote.ConnectionClosedWithHint: Connection closed by remote host. Is borg working on the server?

Platform: Linux ABC 6.1.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.76-1 (2024-02-01) x86_64
Linux: Unknown Linux
Borg: 1.2.4  Python: CPython 3.11.2 msgpack: 1.0.3 fuse: None [pyfuse3,llfuse]
PID: 42470  CWD: /root
sys.argv: ['/usr/bin/borg', 'create', '--remote-path=borg-1.2', '--debug', '--progress', '--stats', '--list', '--show-rc', '--compression', 'lz4', '::{hostname}-db-{now}', 'my-dir']
SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND: None

terminating with error status, rc 2
```

Important note: The Storage box is available, as I am able to backup another machine on it (through borg)

Comment: What is the version of the remote borg? They need the same version

Comment: There is 1.2 as well... The working machine is using borg 1.2.7 without issues...

Comment: One thing to do: `cd /path/to/borg_dirs; mv mysql mysql.20240225; mkdir mysql; cd mysql; borg init ....... ` and try again. If it works, it's the repository is fuc..d up.

Comment: And, what is the output of `borg list $REPOSITORY` after creating mandatory borg's variables from your borg script/command line?

Comment: It is the same connection timeout as the backup...

Comment: Can you try moving the destination repository, then `borg init ......` and try again as already asked? This is reversible.

Comment: I tried to init a new repo and it ends with connection timeout as well... that probably means, there is a connection issue in the SSH, which was somehow caused by the upgrade...

Comment: What is the output of `ssh -vvv XYZ@XYZ.your-storagebox.de:23` on https://pastie.org or qivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that this issue was not related to `borg` after all. Apparently, during upgrade, some firewall rules were lost, including the allowed connections to port 23, therefore the connection died.